# DBDmysql fails installing BugZilla on OS X Mavericks

Tags: mysql, dbi, osx-mavericks, bugzilla, dbd

I am having trouble installing BugZilla on OS X Mavericks.
When I run checksetup.pl it informs me that all required modules are found OK, but it then fails with:

```
Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok: found v4.025 
There was an error connecting to MySQL:

    install_driver(mysql) failed: Attempt to reload DBD/mysql.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 1234) line 3, <DATA> line 577.

 at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 1265.
```

I have confirmed that the db_host, db_name and db_pass entries in localconfig are correct.
I can connect to MySql at the terminal prompt using the same name and password.
I have confirmed that the db_sock entry is correct also.

If I set db_check to 0, it just fails later with the same error.

When I run testserver.pl it passes the test.
I wrote a small php file to test connecting to the database from php and it passes.

I think there must be some DBI or DBD::mysql problem, but how do I check that?